# TSQL with NULL NOT IN clause, will it ever fail or no?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-in, sql-null

While submitting code for my graded project I was pointed that this logic  with `NOT IN` could fail if any Flag has `NULL`  value.  I've did my homework and testing and could not confirm this, my query below always works fine even dealing with `NULL`. Is my professor wrong?  I read about other bad cases with `NOT IN` with NULL but they are bit different with NULL inside parenthesis (eg. `NOT IN ('Alpha',NULL)`  in my case I have defined literals. I just want to make sure that current code is 100% NULL proof.

Can anybody break my theory? Or do we all agree that it's correct.
I'm on most recent SQL 2016 with default setting, which I think by default has ANSI NULL OFF (if it makes any difference). I actually tested my code for ON/OFF without any difference.

I also put my logical interpretation for each case to support my case.
Added: in my case I don't want any NULLs selected, only need to  bring single raw
`4=ID, 'X-Ray' = Flag

```
 DROP TABLE If exists #x
  SELECT * INTO #x FROM (
      SELECT 1 ID, 'Alpha'  Flag   UNION  SELECT 777 ID, NULL     Flag  UNION
      SELECT 3 ID, 'Bravo'  Flag   UNION  SELECT 4   ID, 'X-Ray'  Flag  
 ) a 
 
SELECT  * FROM #x   
WHERE Flag  NOT IN ('Alpha','Bravo')  
--Case#1   'Alpha' <> 'Alpha'   AND   'Alpha' <> 'Bravo'     
--                TRUE                       FALSE          ==> FALSE   (based on True AND False)
--Case#2   'X-Ray' <> 'Alpha'   AND   'X-Ray' <> 'Bravo'    
--                TRUE                       TRUE           ==> TRUE    (TRUE and TRUE)
--Case#3   NULL    <> 'Alpha'   AND   NULL    <> 'Bravo'    
--                UNknown                    UNknown        ==> UKNOWN = not TRUE   (never selected )
```

Comment: Depends on your meaning for `<>`. A lot of people expect `NULL <> 'Alpha'` to pass.

Comment: Thanks Dale, Sorry I meant that we don't need NULLs, in my example we need only bring `X-Ray`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with `null` values that are *within* the argument to `NOT IN()`. So the test case would be:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM #x   
WHERE Flag NOT IN ('Alpha','Bravo', NULL)
```

For your sample data, this [returns no rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69f81273e35c88d96e089d0fb1f13ec0).

Why this behaves like that is because, basically, the database translates `NOT IN` as:

```
WHERE Flag <> 'Alpha' AND Flag <> 'Bravo' AND Flag <> NULL
```

`Flag <> NULL` returns `NULL`, regardless of the value of `Flag`, so the last condition can never be true, and all rows are filtered out. One says that `NOT IN` is not `NULL`-safe.

Of course, if you are using a literal list of values that never contain `NULL` values, then you are fine with `NOT IN`. The problem often arises when subqueries come into play within `NOT IN`.

Comment: Thanks GMB and all,  yes I got this , but for my case having in the list Literals without NULLS like   `not in  ('Alpha','Bravo')` should be OK. No need to do anything special (ISNULL check,etc..)

Comment: @Mich28: if there are no `null` values within `NOT IN()`, then you are fine.